# Remove white spaces from inline form-inputs

Tags: forms, theming

If there is a form generated by drupal form api in template file, is there a way how to remove whitespaces between `.form-input` html elements?

My template looks like this:

```
            <form action="" method="post" id="activit-grant-filter-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <div class="cont"><!--
             --><?php echo render($form['organisation_type']); ?><!-- 
             --><?php echo render($form['locality']); ?><!--         
             --><?php echo render($form['support_type']); ?><!--     
             --><?php echo render($form['thematic_objective']); ?><!--
        --></div>
                <div class="submit-wrapper">
                    <?php echo render($form['submit']); ?>                       
                    <?php echo drupal_render_children($form); ?>
                </div>
            </form>
```

As you can see I'm using comments between form elements, but they're still keeping whitespaces in between.

Comment: Why do you render form-api form like that? You should never need to hardcode `form` tag at all. It's asking for trouble.

Comment: Is there a way how to render `form` tag? I was searching quite a lot but didn't found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set form font size 0 and increase font size of input

```
form {
    font-size: 0;
}

form input {
    font-size: 12px;
```